# How to create a unique slug in waterlines beforeValidate callback?

Tags: node.js, waterline

The problem: I am using Waterline as my ORM with OrientDB in a NodeJS app. OrientDB uses numeric IDs, so I don't want them in my URLs when getting a post. Why? Because it would make it easy to query the complete data by just incrementing the ID.

The solution: Creating a unique slug.

Question: How can this be achieved in Waterline with async callbacks? I need something like this but fail to come up with a solution. The flow is probably like this:

- Create slug
- Check if post with slug exists
- If no, continue with validation
- If yes, change slug and start over

Answer (score 2):

Below is an optimistic solution I'm currently using:

My helper class:

```
// databaseExtensions.js

var _ = require('lodash');

function getUnique(property, value, separator, criteria){
  separator = separator || '-';
  criteria = criteria || {};
  var searchObject = {};
  searchObject[property] = { like: value + '%' };
  _.mergeDefaults(searchObject, criteria);
  return this.find(searchObject)
    .then(function(models){
      if(!models || models.length === 0)
        return value;  // value is unique
      var values = _.pluck(models, property);
      return getUniqueFromArray(values, value, separator);
    });
}


function getUniqueFromArray(existingValues, newValue, separator){
  var valuesArray = _.clone(existingValues);
  var version = 2;  // starting version
  var currentValue = newValue;
  var unique;

  while(version < 10000) { //just to be safe and we don't end up in a infinite     loop
    unique = true;
    for(var i=0; i<valuesArray.length; i++){
      if(currentValue === valuesArray[i]){
        unique = false;
        valuesArray.splice(i, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
    if (unique) {
      return currentValue;
    }
    currentValue = newValue + separator + version;
    version++;
  }
}

module.exports.getUnique = getUnique;
module.exports.getUniqueFromArray = getUniqueFromArray;
```

My model definition:

```
// post.model.js
{
  //..
  atributes: {
    //...
    urlSlug : {
      type : 'string',
      required : true,
      index : true
    }
},
  },
  getUnique: require('path/to/databaseExtensions');.getUnique
}
```

In my controller:

```
// post.controller.js
var slug = require('slug');
slug.defaults.mode ='pretty';

Post.getUnique('urlSlug', slug(post.title).toLowerCase(), '-')
  .then(function(uniqueSlug) { 
    console.log('A new unique slug:', uniqueSlug);
    // assuming inserting title 'title', the results would be
    // title, title-2, title-3, etc
  });
```

In my case collisions are unlikely so I'm not too worried about concurrency issues where 2 models arrive at same time with the same title. But that could be a problem in the context of hundreds of thousands of users creating posts.

Let me know if that doesn't help.

Comment: Thank you! I also created a solution, maybe it's interesting for you. I posted the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with my own solution using [async](https://github.com/caolan/async). In the end I decided against using a unique slug as my identifier and now use a combination of a random string, which I call hash_id, and a slug which doesn't have to be unique and is just there for SEO. But this answer contains a solution for unique slugs as well. So my URLs have this format:

```
http://example.com/posts/23hlj2l2/i_am_a_slug or
http://example.com/posts/:hash_id/:slug
```

I created a helper module to do the string conversion / creation. They just deal with that and know nothing about the ORM or if a value is unique.

The module ModelHelpers exports two methods, one to normalize an input (like title) to create a slug. It accepts an optional parameter which is a number that would be added to the end of the slug.

The second method creates a random alpha-numeric string. You can pass in a parameter for the length of the string.

```
var ModelHelpers = function() {
  // Init
}

ModelHelpers.prototype.createSlugString = function(input_string, added_number) {
  added_number = typeof added_number !== 'undefined' ? added_number : '';

  // First replace all whitespaces and '-' and make sure there are no double _ 
  var clean_string = input_string.replace(/[\s\n\-]+/g, '_').replace(/_{2,}/g, '_');
  // Replace Umlaute and make lowercase
  clean_string = clean_string.toLowerCase().replace(/ä/ig, 'ae').replace(/ö/ig, 'oe').replace(/ü/ig, 'ue');
  // Replace any special characters and _ at the beginning or end
  clean_string = clean_string.replace(/[^\w]/g, '').replace(/^_+|_$/g, '');
  // Only return the first 8 words
  clean_string = clean_string.split("_").slice(0,8).join("_");

  // Add number if needed
  if(added_number !== '') {
    clean_string = clean_string + '_' + added_number.toString();
  }
  return clean_string;
}

ModelHelpers.prototype.makeHashID = function(hash_length)
{
  hash_length = typeof hash_length !== 'undefined' ? hash_length : 10;
  var text = "";
  var possible = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  for( var i=0; i < hash_length; i++ ) {
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
  }
  return text;
}

module.exports = ModelHelpers;
```

The next part of my solution is using Waterlines' lifecycle callback [`beforeValidate`](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/models/lifecycle-callbacks.md) in combination with `async`. This way I can set the slug field or hash id field to unique and it is created before Waterline validates. Async is a very powerful tool and I can only recommend looking into it. I'm using the method `whilst`:

> whilst(test, fn, callback)
>
> Repeatedly call fn, while test returns true. Calls callback when
>   stopped, or an error occurs.

I created two versions, one if you need a random string (hash_id) and one if you want to add a number to the end of your slug if it isn't unique.

**For hash ids:**

```
var Waterline = require('Waterline');
var orientAdapter = require('sails-orientdb');
var ModelHelpers = require('../modules/model-helpers');
var async = require('async');
var mh = new ModelHelpers();

var Post = Waterline.Collection.extend({
    identity: 'post',
    connection: 'myLocalOrient',

    attributes: {

        text: {
            type: 'text',
            required: true
        },

        slug: {
            type: 'string'
        },

        hash_id: {
            type: 'string',
            unique: true
        }
    },
    // Lifecycle Callbacks
    beforeValidate: function(values, next) {
        var model_self = this;
        var keep_running = true;
        // Create first slug
        values.hash_id = mh.makeHashID();
        values.slug = mh.createSlugString(values.text);

        async.whilst(
            function () { 
                // execute whilst while other post has not been retrieved or while it matches a hash_id
                // in the database
                return keep_running;
            },
            function (callback) {
                // search for post with this hash_id
                model_self.findOne().where({hash_id: values.hash_id}).then(function(op) {
                    if(op === undefined) {
                        // Nothing found, stop executing
                        keep_running = false;
                    } else {
                        // Create new hash_id
                        values.hash_id = mh.makeHashID();
                    }
                    callback();
                });
            },
            function (err) {
                // End the process
                // next(); is the callback of Waterlines' beforeValidate
                next();
            }
        ); // End whilst
    }
});

module.exports = Post;
```

**For unique slugs:**

```
var Waterline = require('Waterline');
var orientAdapter = require('sails-orientdb');
var ModelHelpers = require('../modules/model-helpers');
var async = require('async');
var mh = new ModelHelpers();

var Post = Waterline.Collection.extend({
    identity: 'post',
    connection: 'myLocalOrient',

    attributes: {

        text: {
            type: 'text',
            required: true
        },

        slug: {
            type: 'string',
            unique: true
        },

        hash_id: {
            type: 'string'
        }
    },
    // Lifecycle Callbacks
    beforeValidate: function(values, next) {
        var model_self = this;
        var keep_running = true;
        var counter = 0; // we use this to add a number
        // Create first slug
        values.hash_id = mh.makeHashID();
        values.slug = mh.createSlugString(values.text);

        async.whilst(
            function () { 
                // execute whilst while other post has not been retrieved or while it matches a slug
                // in the database
                return keep_running;
            },
            function (callback) {
                counter++;
                // search for post with this slug
                model_self.findOne().where({slug: values.slug}).then(function(op) {
                    if(op === undefined) {
                        // Nothing found, stop executing
                        keep_running = false;
                    } else {
                        // Create new slug
                        values.slug = mh.createSlugString(values.text, counter);
                    }
                    callback();
                });
            },
            function (err) {
                // End the test
                next();
            }
        ); // End whilst
    }
});

module.exports = Post;
```

The advantage of this method is, that it just keeps running until it finds a unique slug/hash_id and that it doesn't care about gaps between the numbers (if slug_2 exists but not slug_1). It also doesn't care about the kind of database you use.

It could still cause problems if by accident two processes write the same slug at the exact same moment, but that would have to happen within miliseconds. And I think the only way to prevent this is lock the table somehow - and I can deal with that if I'm lucky enough to have this problem...

Comment: Cool! Regarding the hash, have you considered using existing solutions as [shortid](https://github.com/dylang/shortid#shortid---) or the beefier (produces longer hashes) [uuid-base62](https://github.com/dmarcelino/uuid-base62#uuid-base62)?